# Wordpress - Trying to remove stubborn title

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have tried removing the title by all the methods I could find on Stackoverflow and wordpress support such as pacing a css rule and finding the get_title in the page, single and template php files. But this title doesn't seem to want to go away.

The only way I have had any success is by using a plugin that removes the title but then I am faced with the problem that the spacing remains where the title once was.

Here is a picture showing what I mean: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZaqe.jpg

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: use css display:none for the html tag

Comment: I tried;
                    `h1.hidden {display:none;}`
 as the code is 
                 `<h1 class="main_title">Home</h1>`
but it does nothing?

Comment: what plugin u used to remove title

Comment: use h1.main_title {display:none;}

Comment: Ahh I see, that worked but I still have the space left there?

Comment: can u post the full css of h1.main_title

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into your template file and remove where the title is being outputted.

I checked the source code on your site and it looks like the theme files are not in the regular place. So do this. Go to your FTP client and open up:

/assets/956/themes/header.php

It might be named something slightly different.

Now within that theme locate your h1 tag. At this point I would recommend removing it, saving it, and making sure you have the desired change. It should be gone completely from the page. If it's not, perhaps the H1 tag is located in another file? Check other template files till you find the right one.

You can remove it all together or surround it in a div with ID='homepg-h1' Then just do a rule like this in your CSS:

```
#homepg-h1 {
    display:none;
}
```

Hope that helps, let me know if you have any questions.